# bash script to replace a string value in a file with an environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a config file named abc.config. I need a bash code to read the app.config file, check every line of the file and replace a specific text called local_host with an environment variable `$MSYSTEM`. Once it's done I want to set the app.config file with the new changes. 
I have assigned the file to a variable

```
$ filecontent=$(</c/app/abc.config)
```

this is okay because when I echo $filecontent, i can see the entire file. After this i am using

```
$ while IFS= read -r line
> do
> filecontent=$(echo $filecontent | sed -e "s/\local_host/$MSYSTEM/g")
> done <"$filecontent"
```

but I get an error `no such file or directory`. I am new to bash as I have been tasked to work with linux containers. Is this the correct way? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need your while loop, you can reduce this all to `sed -i "s/local_host/$MYSYSTEM/g" /c/app/abc.config`, provided that `$MYSYSTEM` doesn't contain forward slashes. If it does, use `${MYSYSTEM//\//\\\/}` to escape them.

Comment: thanks benjamin. That worked. I also tried `sed -i "s/local_host/$MYSYSTEM/g" "$filecontent"` however it outputs the content of the variable filecontent, does not replace local_host with the env variable and gives a `no such file or directory` message in the end. Also wondering if sed commands can be used in bash scripts.